# Proving that evry polynomial of odd degree has at least one root on R

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove a theorem following an analytical ductus: Every polynomial of odd degree has at least one root in R. Here is the way I think I could follow:

I know that polynomials are continuous on the domain of definition. I must find that there exist a partition of R consisting of three domains. The one on which the polynomial takes only strict positive values ( it must thus be an open set and which can be represented as a disjoint union of open Intervals ) the second one on which the polynomial takes only strict negative values ( for reasons of continuity it also be open and  represented as disjoint union of open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$) the third one would be at most a countable set ( algebraic reasons ).

Using the theorem of the intermediate value in analysis it will then be possible, given the continuity of the polynomial to show that precisely the countable set would be the set of the zeros which is then not empty.
The only one thing i can't push forward, even though it seems to me so obvious, is to prove that, given the even degree of the polynimial, it must take at least one positive value and one negative value. Based on the continuity i can then construct or define the positive and negative domains.

My questions are:
 1. Is it the correct way i am following ?
 2. How can i prove that a polynomial of 2n+1 degree must have at least one positive and one negative value ( we know that for a polynomial of degree 2n it must not be the case) ?
3. Is the induction method a way to consider since the linear polynomial takes both values but making the assumption for 2n+1 i am not sure if i have the right to prove it for two degrees higher ( and tus not for all n as supposed by the induction method ) ?
4. can somebody point me out some algebraic way of proving the theorem ?

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Let $p$ be a polynomial of odd degree with real coefficients. Evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty} p(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty} p(x)$. Then, apply the intermediate value theorem. The theorem will not (in some sense) admit a purely algebraic proof because it is not true for polynomials with rational coefficients (restricted to the rational numbers); we need to use the (essentially, analytic) construction of $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Where are the coefficients in? The complex numbers? The real numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this counts as "algebraic", but:

A polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$ has $n$ complex roots.

Prove that, if the coefficients of the polynomial are real[0], and $z$ is a root for $p$, then also its conjugate, $\bar z $ is a root for $p(x)$

So the number of distinct roots must be even, except in the case of some real roots (in this case, $z$ and $\bar z$ are the same)

So if $n$ is odd you must have at least one real root

[0] Which you seem to assume anyway, as for example the complex odd polynomial $p(z) = iz + 1$ has the only complex solution $z = i$. So for your theorem to hold you need to assume that the coefficients are real

---

For your other questions, take the limit as $x \to \pm \infty$. You'll find a positive and a negative value if $n$ is odd, so you'll also show that there is a real root using the intermediate value theorem

Comment: I dont understand what i would get if x runs to infinity ? For each monomial i will get up to a sign infinity, on which i can not apply any algebraic rules.

Comment: @ivo Yes, but in the limit the only term that counts is the highest power. That is, for example, $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 + x = +\infty$, but also $\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2 - x = + \infty$. The lowest powers don't change the outcome of the limit, the only thing that matters is the highest power.

Comment: Thanks. I know what do you mean, which is the highest degree would dominate for some large x the rest of the sum. But is this only intuitive ? Do you know some formal proof of this ?

Comment: @ivo There are lots.. For example use the fact that $$a_nx^n + \dots + a_0 = x^n(a_n + \frac{a_{n-1}}x + \dots + \frac{a_0}{x^n})$$

Now inside the parenthesis you find $a_n$ + a bunch of terms that go to $0$, so multiplying by $x^n$ you'll find $\pm \infty$ (depending on the sign of $a_n$ and the parity of $n$). Clear? :-)

Comment: Very clear, many thanks.

Comment: @ivo You're welcome :) By the way  (since I noticed that you didn't accept any of the answer to your questions): If you've found an answer helpful, and it explained the problem, then you should upvote it and click the little arrow below the vote count. This will mark the answer as accepted and inform the community that you don't need more help. It's fine to wait in the hope of better answers (by all means, do that! :-) ) but sooner or later you should do it :)