# Existence of a real solution to a certain system of inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $x,y,z,w$ be four variables over $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}[x,y,z,w]$ be three homogeneous polynomials, each of degree $3$.

> Is there a real solution to: $B \leq A, B \leq C$? Namely, is there $s=(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta) \in \mathbb{R}^4$, such that 
>   $B(s) \leq A(s), B(s) \leq C(s)$?

**Remarks:** **(1)** I am interested in the existence of such $s \in \mathbb{R}^4$,
not in how to find it exactly. Moreover, I am asking for $s \in \mathbb{R}^4$, not just $s \in \mathbb{C}^4$.

**(2)** Maybe it is possible to obtain a solution by just taking $(x,y,z,w)=(1,1,1,w)$, if (at least) one of the three $\{A,B,C\}$ has degree $3$ in $w$,
and work in $\mathbb{R}[w]$ (and apply [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306743/proving-that-evry-polynomial-of-odd-degree-has-at-least-one-root-on-r?rq=1)). However, I am not sure if this is a solution (probably not necessarily), since it may happen that this solves only one of the two inequalities, not both. (But remember that I have taken very specific $(x,y,z)$, namely, $(1,1,1)$).

**(3)** Perhaps [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92543/consistency-of-systems-of-inequalities-involving-only-differences) is relevant.

I really apologize if my question is quite obscure; it is just that I have calculated something and arrived at such a situation.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tilde{A}(s) = A(s) - B(s)$ and $\tilde{C}(s) = C(s) - B(s)$. 
Since $A, B, C$ are homogeneous of degree $3$, so do $\tilde{A}$ and $\tilde{C}$.  For any $s \in \mathbb{R}^4$, we have $\tilde{A}(-s) = -\tilde{A}(s)$ and $\tilde{C}(-s) = -\tilde{C}(s)$.

Using continuity of $\tilde{A}$, we can find a point $t \in \mathbb{R}^4$ with $|t| = 1$ and $\tilde{A}(t) = \tilde{A}(-t) = 0$. Since at least one of $\tilde{C}(t)$ or $\tilde{C}(-t) \ge 0$. We have find a $s = t$ or $-t$ such that $|s| = 1$ and

$$\tilde{A}(s) = 0, \tilde{C}(s) \ge 0 \quad\iff\quad A(s) = B(s), C(s) \ge B(s)$$

Comment: Nice answer, thank you very much!

Comment: I have tried to generalize your idea to the following case, but have not succeeded yet; any ideas are welcome: $A,B,C,D,E \in \mathbb{R}[x,y,z,w]$ are homogeneous of degree $5$. I am looking for a solution $s \in \mathbb{R}^4$ to the $6$ inequalities $B \leq A, B \leq C, B \leq E, D \leq A,  D \leq C, D \leq E$. Now, define: $A_B=A-B,C_B=C-B,E_B=E-B,A_D=A-D,C_D=C-D,E_D=E-D$; clearly all the six polynomials are homogeneous of degree $5$, so they are odd polynomials ($A_B(-s)=-A_B(s)$ etc.). By continuity, we can find $s \in \mathbb{R}^4$ such that $A_B(s)=0,C_B(s) \geq 0$.

Comment: But the remaining $4$ inequalities may be either $\leq 0$ or $\geq 0$, so such $s$ is not (yet?) a solution. Hopefully, something can be done also in this case, and in any higher odd homogeneous degrees.

Comment: My above comments (slightly changed, with $4$ inequalities instead of $6$, so perhaps something can be done) are now the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2847838/existence-of-a-real-solution-to-a-certain-system-of-inequalities-generalized?noredirect=1&lq=1